# How to format dates using implyr in R?

Tags: r, dplyr, hdfs, impala

I'm using the `implyr` package in R to collect data from HDFS/Impala. I would like to format a field that is currently formatted as a timestamp in Impala as **YYYYMM** prior to collecting the data in R. Here is my code:

```
library(implyr); library(dplyr) 
data %>%
    select(date_field) %>%
    mutate(yyyymm = as.Date(date_field, format = '%Y%m'))
```

**Note:** I need this completed *prior* to collecting from Impala.

Using the `show_query()` function, I receive the following:

```
SELECT AS.DATE(date_field, '%Y%m' as "format") as yyyymm
FROM data
Warning message:
Named arguments ignored for SQL AS.DATE
```

Since `implyr` is working as a backend to `dplyr` for Impala, my question is this - Does anyone know if there exists code that will format the date accordingly **and** convert to a recognizable Impala query? It seems to me that the conversion just wasn't successful (re: `AS.DATE(date_field, '%Y%m' as "format") as yyyymm`). I'm really hoping the issue is solvable through `dplyr` syntax?

I've looked at the author's documentation https://github.com/ianmcook/implyr and through questions on stack, but haven't been able to figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** 
I am able to get to this point: 
`library(implyr); library(dplyr) 
data %>%
    select(date_field) %>%
    mutate(yyyy = year(date_field), mm = month(date_field))`

Which produces:

```
Date_Field                 yyyy    mm
2015-04-13 19:33:26.000    2015     4
```

However, if I add on a `%>% mutate(yyyymm = paste0(yyyy,mm))`, the error is in the Impala query `errorMessage:AnalysisException: No matching function with signature: concat(INT, INT)`. So what I need to do is convert the `yyyy` and `mm` objects into strings before concatenating them so that Impala recognizes it. In Impala, it would look something like this:

`select date_field
, concat(cast(year(date_field) as string), cast(month(date_field) as string)) as yyyymm
from data`

and gives me what I'm looking for:

```
Date_Field               yyyymm
2015-04-13 19:33:26      20154
```

with the small exception of the month formatting, which should be able to be fixed with something like `lpad` in Impala, but I don't care about this for my purposes. So what I need to figure out is how to appropriately convert the `yyyy` and `mm` fields in my `dplyr` R code to strings before executing the `paste0` function.

Comment: So you need to format a date like `201804` into what?

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly. I need to format `2018-04-05 16:32:35` to `201804` while piping so I can then group by the new YYYYMM date field. Since `implyr` is converting this into a query in Impala, I'm not sure what the appropriate `dplyr` code would be to do this formatting.

Comment: ping ping to the author @ianmcook :) If no response, I would suggest to submit an issue at GitHub with link to this post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Since my last edit in my question, the fix simply needed to add the following:

```
    mutate(yyyy = as.character(yyyy), mm = as.character(mm)) %>%
    mutate(yyyymm = paste0(yyyy,mm))
```

So the full solution would be:

```
library(implyr); library(dplyr) 
data %>%
    select(date_field) %>%
    mutate(yyyy = year(date_field), mm = month(date_field)) %>%
    mutate(yyyy = as.character(yyyy), mm = as.character(mm)) %>%
    mutate(yyyymm = paste0(yyyy,mm))
```

The problem was that I needed to do this in steps so that Impala would recognize it as an executable query.

Answer (score 1):

In the as.Date() function, the format you should pass to the argument is the one the data is in, not the one you want it to be converted.

Using the package lubridate, I reproduced your problem and this worked for me:

```
 library(lubridate)

 paste0(year(as.Date(date_field, "%Y-%m-%d")), month(as.Date(date_field, "%Y-%m-%d")))
```

You just need to pass this inside your mutate call.

Comment: Thanks for the response, however, this doesn't seem to fix my issue. Doing `data %>% select(date_field) %>% mutate(yyyymm = paste0(year(as.Date(date_field, "%Y-%m-%d")), month(as.Date(date_field, "%Y-%m-%d")))) %>% select(yyyymm)` shows a syntax error pointing to `concat(YEAR(AS.DATE(`date_field`, '%Y-%...`, which is unfortunately similar to what was happening before.

Comment: Please see my edit in my question above. @GiovanaStein

Comment: after that last edit, my solution was pretty trivial - see my answer below